# C# Open Weather Map other informations

Tags: c#, openweathermap

I try to make a program for learn. I have a problem with it, i tried lots of times to get other informations, like air pressure and other.
Now just this work: Date, Longitude, latitude, Country, time, temperature.

So, how can i get other datas?

```
        XmlNode loc_node = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("weatherdata/location");
        txtCity.Text = loc_node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        txtCountry.Text = loc_node.SelectSingleNode("country").InnerText;
        XmlNode geo_node = loc_node.SelectSingleNode("location");
        txtLat.Text = geo_node.Attributes["latitude"].Value;
        txtLong.Text = geo_node.Attributes["longitude"].Value;
        txtId.Text = geo_node.Attributes["geobaseid"].Value;
        XmlNode main_node = loc_node.SelectSingleNode("main");
        textBox1.Text = main_node.Attributes["pressure"].Value;
```

The Last 2 not working.

UPDATE*

XML example.
This is 1 hour, i split from my xml.
(Sorry for picture)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9pWk.png)

Comment: Could you please also add an XML snippet to ensure others can help you?

Comment: seems like you should specify main_node.Attributes["pressure"]["value].Value;

Comment: right now you are looking for pressure which contains two fields inside, the Value Property on the Attribute is not the "value" you are looking for